# android httpconnection timeout not working

Tags: android, timeout, httpurlconnection

when i turn on internet(data)  dialog.dismiss(); works fine and dialog go away. but if i turn off internet dialog is not going away.i waited 1min or more. by the way this is a background thread.
i dont need to check internet. just want to timeout and need to run   dialog.dismiss(); after connection work done or timeout. 
my code is

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://anything.com/a/?enask="+textsearched )).openConnection();
 connection.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
 connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
 connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
 connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
  connection.setDoInput( true );
 connection.setDoOutput( true );
 connection.connect();
 InputStream is = null;
 is = connection.getInputStream();
 dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: are you displaying your progressdialog in a async task??

Comment: yes async task progressdialog go away when got html data. but when no internet available progressdialog  wont go away.

Comment: so add that interent checking condition on your asynctask pre execute method.If internet not available then dialog.dismiss();

Comment: i dont need to check internet. just want to timeout and need to run dialog.dismiss(); after connection work done or timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if you are online first.

```
    public boolean isOnline() 
        {
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) 
            {return true;}
        return false;
        }
```

And dismiss otherwise

Comment: sir can you tell me a way to run dialog.dismiss(); after html data got or timeout after atleast 15secounds.